# Is there a way to avoid 'Add Tester user' for Instagram Basic User API or Graph API?

Tags: api, facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Im trying to use the Instagram API and I need to retrieve the most recent photos of a public account.

I manage to do it with a fake account created by me following the steps of [this post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-the-instagram-basic-display-api-5124c92c4935), but the thing is I dont want to do the process of "add a Test User to the app, this User needs to accept he will be testing the app, etc".

I just want to send them the authorization link:
[image: authorization link]

and get the access token, for later to be able to get the user id and retrieve the recent photos.
Basically, is it possible to avoid the 'Add Test user' part to later be able to obtain the photos of this user? maybe with the Graph API?

By the way, if I try to retrieve the access token without adding the tester user, once I log into the account (the one with the photos I want to scrape) and accept the permissions and all of that, I get these
[image: failed-access-token]

I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance :)

**P.S. If you need any more info or details i can happily answer with that info you need.**

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solutions?